# What ports does Skype for Business Web Client use?

Tags: lync, skype-for-business-2016

An external customer is having problems attending our Skype for Business meeting.  It is hosted online through Office 365.

They do not have S4B and are using the web client.  They can join and use IM but not desktop sharing or audio.  We suspect they have a very strict firewall in place.

I had assumed the web client would simply use standard web ports.
What other ports might the client need?

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2409256/you-can-t-connect-to-skype-for-business-online--or-certain-features-do

Comment: In addition to the suggestions posted in the comment, it may be worth confirming what browser the customer is using and the permissions associated with it.  I've worked with some who are forced to use a locked down version of IE and cannot use Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: The web client plug in uses ports 443 and 444 as noted in this KnowledgeBase post from a service provider: https://kb.intermedia.net/Article/1679

Comment: Wrote this a while ago. IMHO, Skype and Business do not mix well: http://www.nightbluefruit.com/blog/2014/05/is-skype-an-appropriate-tool-in-corporate-environments/

Answer (score 0):

I have only seen that the client is using http and https (more infos [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg425820.aspx)). But to be on the save side you could run fiddler and check which ports will be used here (including hostnames if you need).

However we had customers who reported the same, so here is the summary for the issues and solutions we collected so far (as we run a very big environment, there are a lot to share):

- locked down rights on the PC & Internet Explorer which caused that the correct plugins couldn´t run correctly
- incorrectly configured headset, where the MIC wasn´t allowed to be used as recording device in the system settings
- Locked down USB ports which do not accept the headset they wish to use. Strangly audio was working, however not the MIC, after whitelisting the USB device by the local IT in there USB management environment it started to work.
- One customer hat a damaged browser installation. Google chrome caused exactly these issues reported, however IE was running fine.
- For some customers not all Microsoft cloud IPs for Office 365 are open. They initially opened some of them, however the cloud was/is changing. This caused that the could join, however audio wasn´t working due to that issue.
- A software on the PC blocked audio & video streams. We do not got more info's here as the IT from that company re-configured that software but according our info's it was some kind of DLP (Data Leak Prevention).

*By the way, the best would be if you run a test on your side as well to ensure that there is no configuration issue on your side somehow. While you do that you could run fiddler and validate the needed ports and hostnames/ips.*